# batch file repeating previous working program

Tags: batch-file

Please I need help regarding my batch script. It was running perfectly, but later on when I wanted to run it keep repeating my previous result it displayed. eg I executed a program last week called to run echo " The program run at first last week", and by the time I tried to run it today by echo " This is today". It ran and displayed the previous result "

PS The code is working perfectly now....
@echo off

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set file="C:\compress.gdb"


if not exist %file% goto :EOF
FOR %%A IN (%file%) DO set size=%%~zA

>"%temp%\math.vbs" echo Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments: num = objArgs(0) : result = 0
>>"%temp%\math.vbs" echo if num ^> 1073741824 then result=1
>>"%temp%\math.vbs" echo if num ^> 6442450944 then result=2
>>"%temp%\math.vbs" echo Wscript.echo result

for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\math.vbs" %size% ') do set z=%%a

del "%temp%\math.vbs"

:: z will be 2 if %size% greater than 6442450944
:: z will be 1 if %size% greater than 1073741824
:: z will be 0 if %size% less    than 1073741825

echo %z%

if %z% EQU 2 (goto EXECUTE)
if %z% EQU 0 (goto LOGOUT)
if %z% EQU 1 (goto LOGOUT)

goto :EOF

:EXECUTE

call "C:\Batch_Scripts_Sensitive\message.rtf" /max
"C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\InterBase\bin\isql" -i "C:\Batch_Scripts_Sensitive\Empty_Tables_2.sql" localhost:"C:\Program Files (x86)\GE Aviation\AB139 HGS\DB\compress.GDB" -user xxxxxxx -pass xxxxxxx

:: Create Date for Back up and Restore

set hour=%time:~0,2%
if "%hour:~0,1%" == " " set hour=0%hour:~1,1%
echo hour=%hour%
set min=%time:~3,2%
if "%min:~0,1%" == " " set min=0%min:~1,1%
echo min=%min%
set secs=%time:~6,2%
if "%secs:~0,1%" == " " set secs=0%secs:~1,1%
echo secs=%secs%

set year=%date:~-4%
echo year=%year%
set month=%date:~3,2%
if "%month:~0,1%" == " " set month=0%month:~1,1%
echo month=%month%
set day=%date:~0,2%
if "%day:~0,1%" == " " set day=0%day:~1,1%
echo day=%day%

rem use this if you want to add seconds rem set datetimef=mydate_%year%_%month%_%day%_%hour%:%min%:%secs%
set datetimef=%year%_%month%_%day%_%hour%%min%
echo datetimef=%datetimef%
mkdir "C:\Monthly-gdb-restore\%datetimef%"


copy "C:\compress.gdb" "C:\Monthly-gdb-restore\%datetimef%" /Y


:: Delete empty folder in this location %Datetime%

for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir "C:\Monthly-gdb-restore" /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%d"


forfiles /P "C:\Monthly-gdb-restore"  /S /M *.gdb /D -7 /C "cmd /c del @PATH /q"

"C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\InterBase\bin\gbak"   -b "C:\compress.gdb" "C:\compress.ibk"  -user xxxxxxx -password xxxxxxx

set hour=%time:~0,2%
if "%hour:~0,1%" == " " set hour=0%hour:~1,1%
echo hour=%hour%
set min=%time:~3,2%
if "%min:~0,1%" == " " set min=0%min:~1,1%
echo min=%min%
set secs=%time:~6,2%
if "%secs:~0,1%" == " " set secs=0%secs:~1,1%
echo secs=%secs%

set year=%date:~-4%
echo year=%year%
set month=%date:~3,2%
if "%month:~0,1%" == " " set month=0%month:~1,1%
echo month=%month%
set day=%date:~0,2%
if "%day:~0,1%" == " " set day=0%day:~1,1%
echo day=%day%

rem use this if you want to add seconds rem set datetimef=mydate_%year%_%month%_%day%_%hour%:%min%:%secs%
set datetimef=%year%_%month%_%day%_%hour%%min%
echo datetimef=%datetimef%
mkdir "C:\Monthly-ibk-backup\%datetimef%"

copy "C:\compress.ibk"   "C:\Monthly-ibk-backup\%datetimef%"  /Y

:: Delete empty folder in this location %Datetime%

for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir "C:\Monthly-ibk-backup" /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%d"

forfiles /P "C:\Monthly-ibk-backup"  /S /M *.ibk /D -7 /C "cmd /c del @PATH /q"

"C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\InterBase\bin\gbak"  -R "C:\compress.ibk" "C:\compress.gdb" -user xxxxxxx -password xxxxxxx

 goto FINISH


:LOGOUT

Echo " The size of the database file is not up to 6GB

goto :EOF

:FINISH

ECHO " The database for xxxxxxx  was up to 6GB OR MORE, therefore proper backup and restoration has been performed.





goto :EOF
```

Comment: set file="C:\Program Files (x86)\GE Aviation\AB139 HGS\DB\AW139 DB.gdb"
set minbytesize=6442450944
set gigbytesize=1073741824

if exist %file% (FOR %%A IN (%file%) DO set size=%%~zA)

if "%size%" GEQ "%minbytesize%" (goto EXECUTE) 
if not "%size%" GEQ "%minbytesize%" (goto LOGOUT)

Comment: @MichealOshaye - you should edit that into your question - it'll make it easier to read, for one thing.

Comment: I have put the code there in the question section.

Comment: @MichealOshaye you should not post confidential material in a public forum. Also not partially secret code.

Comment: I have removed any other info that can be sensitive and most path files are common examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running it in the same console window both times then the problem will likely be an uninitialised variable, and you are seeing the last result.

To use VBS to check the numbers then try this as the first part of your code.
Leave in the last `goto :eof` to stop it falling through the compare into the following code.

Check the final if compares to be sure they are doing what you want.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set file="C:\Program Files (x86)\GE Aviation\AB139 HGS\DB\AW139 DB.gdb"


if not exist %file% goto :EOF
FOR %%A IN (%file%) DO set size=%%~zA

>"%temp%\math.vbs" echo Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments: num = objArgs(0) : result = 0
>>"%temp%\math.vbs" echo if num ^> 1073741824 then result=1
>>"%temp%\math.vbs" echo if num ^> 6442450944 then result=2
>>"%temp%\math.vbs" echo Wscript.echo result

for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\math.vbs" %size% ') do set z=%%a

del "%temp%\math.vbs"

:: z will be 2 if %size% greater than 6442450944
:: z will be 1 if %size% greater than 1073741824
:: z will be 0 if %size% less    than 1073741825

if %z% EQU 2 (goto EXECUTE) 
if %z% EQU 1 (goto EXECUTE) 
if %z% EQU 0 (goto LOGOUT)

goto :EOF
```

Comment: What can I do to stop this?

Comment: I think jeb might be on the right track.  But are you running it in the same console window days apart?

Comment: Yes, I am running it days apart. Yes, I am running it days apart. Before, it was running fine as intended, but suddenly changed recently. That is the reason I said it may not be the size issue. When I remove quotes from the if and for statement, it works and then again start some strange things. I was thinking about uninitialise variables.

Comment: Thank you Foxdrive. This is also coming into play. How can I write a script to close the cmd running. I have closed the cmd, but not sure if it will be running else wheree. Any tips. I was thinking about also dividing the size file with 1024 before I compare.

Comment: Foxdrive, It is working properly again when I created a new .bat file. But  the situation is this server never shut down or restart. I think it may require restarting PC to make it work again. How can someone do the clean up of the cmd.exe. Thanks, Michael

Comment: Should I include the :EXECUte and :LOGOUT below goto EOF. This will be a perfect option for me. When I run it, the cmd windows closes without display within seconds.

Comment: Yes put the rest of your code below the `goto :eof` and check that the two if conditions are doing what they should.  Above the two if conditions add `echo %z% & pause` and you will see the result code before the script branches to execute or logoff.

Comment: It gives this error Microsoft VBScript runtime error : Subscript out of range.

Comment: Did you change anything?  How big is the filesize?  It looks to me like you executed the script on it's own.  Don't do that. :)

Comment: The file size is 5gb. I did not change anything. I did as you said. But the del "del "%temp%\math.vbs" is not clear to me because we are deleting the math library if am right. The starange thing is that when I executed the script ( Without the VBScript) on the 5GB file, it goes to EXECUte, instead of LOGOUT. Thanks for your time

Comment: It works here.  I can't see your end to tell what is going wrong. Try copy and pasting it again.

Comment: Ok, I will do that tomorrow. Just off the network that I am using. Thanks for everything so far, but I do not want to go back and start writing in another program. I have drawn out this plan very well and If I had known that windows cmd will be like repeating and give false output then I would have opt out and used another program am not sure which one to use. I still have many times of these files to implement it on, and you interbase file size grow at large and so doing automation will help greatly with this script. Looking forward to working with you on this later on.

Comment: Foxdrive, I have pasted the code in order for you to see it. It is just the file name that changed. Cheers.

Comment: Foxdrive, it is working perfectly now. I used the same code and because I have to include the if %z% EQU 1 (goto EXECUTE) since the 5gb fall between 6gb and 1gb. I have tested it rigorously, and I will say that your code has been perfect. Thank you so much. How can I rate this has been answered. The VBscript has helped alot. I will just remove pause now........Cheers

Comment: Glad to hear it.  You might have copied it as I made an edit which is why it failed.   You can accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have accepted the answers because it works well. How do I mark this as answered?

Answer (score 7):

The number in `set minbytesize=6442450944` is to big.
Batch can only handle 32bit numbers.

But as you quote the numbers the string compare function will be used, so a size of `"9"` will be greater than `"6442450944"`.

To get a *correct* compare you can prefix the number with zeros, in your case it's simple as you know how long the second number is.

```
...
set "size=000000000000%size%"
set "size=%size:~-10%"
if "%size%" GEQ "%minbytesize%" (goto EXECUTE)
```

It's still a string compare, but it's also correct for numbers now.

Btw. This will not be your main problem.
It could be a good idea to set `ECHO ON` to see where your problem occurs.

What time format you are using?
If it's using prefixed zeros for the hour you got problems at `set /a hh=%hh%+100`

Comment: Thanks jeb, But the situation can not be the size because it was working properly before and so am not sure if it is the size issue precise. It is windows 7 with 64 bit version. I have put the full code to underrstand the program.

Comment: Jeb, what about if I want to divide it by 1024 to convert to Megabytes ? How should I do that using Set /A?   How can I convert the file itself using approriate variables in order to make the script handle 32 bits number. Cheers, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks jeb,  the file aw 139 is 800 MB yet it stioll go to EXECUTe after using the codes you suggested. Look at the way I define it: 1.    
    if exist %file% (FOR %%A IN (%file%) DO (set size=%%~zA ) )
    set "size=000000000000%size%"
    set "size=%size:~-10%"
    if "%size%" GEQ "%minbytesize%" (goto EXECUTE) 
    if not "%size%" GEQ "%minbytesize%" (goto EXECUTE)

Comment: Now it works when I removed the " " from the If that contains size and minbytesize. It goes to LOGOUT. Again when the file is now more than 6GB, it will require me to put the quotes back. I just do not understand.

Comment: There exists a great article from dbenham [Rules for how CMD.EXE parses numbers](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=19880#p19880)