# Update running unsigned long long sum in bat file

Tags: batch-file

Is there a simple way to sum two numbers potentially >= 2*31 in a .BAT file?
I have a running sum, and argument %1 that is the name of an existing file.

```
set sum=4123456789
set fsize=%~z1
```

I'd like to add fsize to sum.  Unfortunately fsize (and sum) can be as tiny as zero or 10's of gigabytes (**%~z1** accurately reports >= 2*31 file sizes).

I know a program could do it, and I'll go that route if necessary, but I'd prefer to do it with a few added lines of .BAT logic.

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17192351/2152082)

Comment: Batch itself only supports 32bit numbers, but you can write your own math library. Some simple sampels are at [robvanderwoude.com](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_math.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to split the summands into two parts – integer and fractional Gigas (multiples of `1000000000`), add the respective parts individually, then recombine them. See the following example script, which contains a lot of explanatory remarks:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Initialise variables:
set /A "GIGASUM=0, FRACSUM=0"

:LOOP
rem // Get command line argument:
shift
set "NUM=%~0"
if not defined NUM goto :NEXT

rem // Check number for validity:
(for /F "delims=0123456789" %%N in ("%NUM%") do rem/) && (
    echo ERROR: non-numeric characters encountered!
    exit /B 1
)

rem // Split number into two parts, integer and fractional Gigas:
set "NUM=000000000%NUM%"
set "GIGA=%NUM:~,-9%" & set "FRAC=%NUM:~-9%"

rem // Remove leading zeros from integer Gigas:
for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("%GIGA%") do set "GIGA=%%N"

rem // Sum up fractional Gigas and determine carry:
set /A "FRACSUM+=(1%FRAC%-1000000000)"
set "CARRY=%FRACSUM:~,-9%" & set "FRACSUM=000000000%FRACSUM%"
set "FRACSUM=%FRACSUM:~-9%"

rem // Sum up integer Gigas and regard carry:
set /A "GIGASUM+=GIGA+CARRY"

rem // Loop back to next summand:
goto :LOOP

:NEXT
rem // Remove leading zeros:
for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("%GIGASUM%%FRACSUM%") do set "SUM=%%N"
if not defined SUM set "SUM=0"

rem // Return resulting sum:
echo %SUM%

endlocal
exit /B
```

The greatest possible sum amounts to `231 * 109 – 1 = 2147483647999999999`, an overflow is not detected.

Comment: I only thought of the single digit approach, which seemed too much -- you put me on track.  Now I init via: `set /a sh=sl=0`  I update sum via: `set /a sh+=%fsize:~0,-9%+0, sl+=%fsize:~-9%, sh+=sl/1000000000, sl%%=1000000000`  The sum at any time is sl (if sh is 0) or  sh contatenated with sl (after padding sl to length 9 with any necessary leading zeroes).

Comment: `sl+=%fsize:~-9%` can cause trouble when it holds leading zeros as such indicate octal numbers (see `set /?`); you can avoid that by `sl+=1%fsize:~-9%%%1000000000` instead...

Comment: Thank you... missed that!  I have been bitten by the lead-zero-triggers-octal bug many times, and have bemoaned the fact that "feature" exists in any language on stackoverflow before.  Does anyone actual use octal?  Ok, I admit I am showing my bias and limited background (and frustration).

Comment: I guess almost everybody who once used `set /A` fell into the octal-trap... I'd love to have a prefix like `0o` for octal numbers, then it'd be obvious, but defining `0` as the prefix appears just stupid to me...

Comment: `sl+=1%fsize:~-9%%%1000000000` yields incorrect results when %fsize% is less than 9 digits.  I fixed this by restricting `sl` to hold only 8 digits and changing the summation step to `set /a sh+=%fsize:~0,-8%+(sl+=1%fsize:~-8%%%(2%fsize:~-8%-1%fsize:~-8%))/100000000, sl%%=100000000`

Comment: Yes, `sl+=1%fsize:~-9%%%1000000000` only works properly in case `fsize` has been padded to hold at least 9 digits by `set "fsize=000000000%fsize%"` first...

Answer (score 0):

The required logic is not so complicated. Here it is one version:

```
@echo off
setlocal

:loop
set /p "pair=Enter two numbers separated by plus sign: "
if errorlevel 1 goto :EOF

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=+" %%a in ("%pair%") do set "num1=%%a" & set "num2=%%b"
set "sum="
set "carry=0"
:nextDigit
   set /A sum1=%num1:~-1%+%num2:~-1%+carry
   set "sum=%sum1:~-1%%sum%"
   set /A carry=sum1/10
   set "num1=%num1:~0,-1%"
   if not defined num1 set "num1=0"
   set "num2=%num2:~0,-1%"
   if not defined num2 set "num2=0"
if "%carry%%num1%%num2%" neq "000" goto nextDigit

echo The sum is: %sum%
goto loop
```